# NodeJS spawn stdout string format

Tags: node.js, stdout, spawn

I'm spawning a process in node and tracking the output of the command like this:

```
proc.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

It works well, however, the output seems to be splitting the lines:

```
npm http
 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
```

The above is just one line out of the response from an `npm install`. Typically this is all in one line, it's also adding line breaks before and after the response. Is there a way to get the data output to look like the standard run, i.e. line-by-line?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Streams are buffered and emit `data` events whenever they please (so to speak), not on strict boundaries like lines of text.

But you can use the [`readline`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module to parse the buffers into lines for you:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var readline      = require('readline');
var proc          = child_process.spawn(...);

readline.createInterface({
  input     : proc.stdout,
  terminal  : false
}).on('line', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 solutions which come to mind:

```
// solution #1
process.stdout.write(data);

// solution #2
console.log(data.toString().replace(/[\n\r]/g, ""));

// solution #3
var child_process = require('child_process');
var readline = require('readline');
var proc = child_process.spawn(...);
readline.createInterface({
  input: proc.stdout,
  terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
});
```